# Substitutions with psfrag not compiling. Can I use includegraphics?

Tags: graphics, eps, psfrag

I am trying to compile this code with "latex" (not pdflatex).

I got the code itself from a collegue, so it should work. Except maybe the way I compile it and the usepackage options?

Right now, I am getting the error:

```
" ...graphics[width = 0.54\textwidth]{SVM2.eps ! Undefined control sequence."
```

I shouldn't use graphics in Latex right? Since it is an eps figure. Any ideas?

The eps file is available [here.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13564139/SVM2.eps)

UPDATE

I forget to include some newcommands, as was remarked below. This is the corrected code. It compiles, but the substitutions appear next to the graph. I thought they were supposed to come inside the graph.

```
\documentclass{article} 
%  \usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\vecbeta}{\boldsymbol{\beta}}
\newcommand{\vecX}{\mbox{\boldmath$x$}}
\newcommand{\vecW}{\boldsymbol{w}}
\newcommand{\natnumbers}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
\newcommand{\varphibold}{\mbox{\boldmath$\varphi$}}\newcommand{\vecvarphi}{\mbox{\boldmath$\varphi$}}
\newcommand{\xibold}{\mbox{\boldmath$\xi$}}
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\ul}{\underline}
\newcommand{\nubold}{\mbox{\boldmath$\nu$}}
\newcommand{\alphabold}{\mbox{\boldmath$\alpha$}}
\def\bkRrm{{\rm I\kern-.17em R}}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\begin{document}   
\begin{psfrags}
\psfrag{x}[][]{x}
\psfrag{+}[][]{+}
\psfrag{E1}[][]{\ \ \ \footnotesize{${\bf w}^T\varphibold({\bf x})+b=-1$}}
\psfrag{E2}[][]{\ \ \ \ \footnotesize{${\bf w}^T\varphibold({\bf x})+b=0$}}
\psfrag{E3}[][]{\ \ \ \ \footnotesize{${\bf w}^T\varphibold({\bf x})+b=+1$}}
\psfrag{E4}[][]{$\varphibold_1({\bf x})$}
\psfrag{E5}[][]{$\varphibold_2({\bf x})$}
\psfrag{E6}[][]{$2/||{\bf w}||$}
\psfrag{E7}[][]{Class +1}
\psfrag{E8}[][]{Class -1}
  \includegraphics[width = 0.54\textwidth]{SVM2.eps}
  \end{psfrags}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `graphicx` in latex or pdflatex however you don't need to explicitly refer to it as it is loaded by `psfrag`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't show the important part of the error message. The undefined command is `\varphibold`.

From the name I guess you want a definition like

```
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand\varphibold{\bm{\varphi}}
```

using `latex`, `dvips`, ps2pdf`, on the posted code I get the expected result:

[image]

Comment: Oh, you are absolutely right, I forgot to paste my newcommands in the file. I have edited my original question. This time, no compile errors, but the substitutions appear next to the picture.

Comment: @dorien works for me, see update.

Comment: Thanks, apparently the dvips is a necessary step, that fixed it!